# Using Unity3d NetworkTransport.Receive's receiver connection id results in messages delivered to self

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a client server model using Unity3d's `NetworkTransport` (LLAPI). I'm bumping in to an issue where a client connects to the server, sends a "ping" message to the server and the server responding with a "pong".

On the client side the ping message goes out fine and the server receives it. However when the server response to the client with a pong message it goes awkwardly wrong as the server ends up sending the "pong" to it self using the remote connection id.

Here's a simplified example with a client and a server.

**The client**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class NetworkClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string host = "127.0.0.1";
    public int port = 8000;

    private int hostId;
    private int connectionId;
    private ConnectionConfig config;
    private HostTopology hostTopology;
    private byte channelId;

    void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        byte error;
        config = new ConnectionConfig();
        channelId = config.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        hostTopology = new HostTopology(config, 1);
        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(hostTopology);

        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, host, port, 0, out error);
        NetworkError networkError = (NetworkError)error;
        if (networkError != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("Unable to connect to {0}:{1}, Error: {2}", host, port, networkError));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Connected to {0}:{1} with hostId: {2}, connectionId: {3}, channelId: {4},", host, port, hostId, connectionId, channelId));
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int recHostId;
        int recConnectionId;
        int recChannelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType networkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out recConnectionId, out recChannelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        NetworkError networkError = (NetworkError)error;
        if (networkError != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("Error recieving event: {0} with recHostId: {1}, recConnectionId: {2}, recChannelId: {3}", networkError, recHostId, recConnectionId, recChannelId));
        }

        switch (networkEvent)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                if (recConnectionId == connectionId)
                    print("success with connection");
                else
                    print("got connection");
                Debug.Log(string.Format("incoming connection event received with connectionId: {0}, recHostId: {1}, recChannelId: {2}", recConnectionId, recHostId, recChannelId));
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(recBuffer);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                string message = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;
                Debug.Log("incoming message event received: " + message);

                SendSocketMessage();
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("remote client " + recConnectionId + " disconnected");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SendSocketMessage()
    {
        byte error;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, "Ping");
        int bufferSize = 1024;

        NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
        NetworkError networkError = (NetworkError)error;
        if (networkError != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("client: Error: {0}, hostId: {1}, connectionId: {2}, channelId: {3}", networkError, hostId, connectionId, channelId));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Message sent!");
        }
    }
}
```

**The server**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class NetworkServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int port = 8000;

    private HostTopology topology;
    private ConnectionConfig config;
    private int connectionId;
    private int hostId;
    private byte channelId;

    void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        config = new ConnectionConfig();
        channelId = config.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        topology = new HostTopology(config, 10);
        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topology, port);
        Debug.Log("Server started on port" + port + " with id of " + hostId);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int recHostId;
        int recConnectionId;
        int recChannelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType networkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out recConnectionId, out recChannelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        NetworkError networkError = (NetworkError)error;
        if (networkError != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("Error recieving event: {0} with recHostId: {1}, recConnectionId: {2}, recChannelId: {3}", networkError, recHostId, recConnectionId, recChannelId));
        }

        switch (networkEvent)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log(string.Format("incoming connection event received with connectionId: {0}, recHostId: {1}, recChannelId: {2}", recConnectionId, recHostId, recChannelId));
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(recBuffer);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                string message = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;
                Debug.Log("incoming message event received: " + message);

                SendSocketMessage(recConnectionId, channelId);
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("remote client " + recConnectionId + " disconnected");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SendSocketMessage(int remoteConnectionId, int channelId)
    {
        byte error;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, "Pong");
        int bufferSize = 1024;

        NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, remoteConnectionId, channelId, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
        NetworkError networkError = (NetworkError)error;
        if (networkError != NetworkError.Ok)
        {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("server: Error: {0}, hostId: {1}, connectionId: {2}, channelId: {3}", networkError, hostId, remoteConnectionId, channelId));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Message sent!");
        }
    }
}
```

The server, when it receives the `NetworkEventType.DataEvent` it responds with a "pong" message using the `remoteConnectionId`. Unfortunately the documentation is a little bit lacking and I'm assuming that the `recConnectionId` inside the `Update()` method is the connection id of the remote host (i.e. the connected client) and can be used to respond to  with messages.

When you run this program the server will receive the ping message and responds to itself with a "pong" and ends up in a loop replying to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem to my issue. This is the classic problem with having a design that involves many singletons (on Unity's part).

Because `NetworkTransport` is a singleton and because (for testing purposes) both the client and the server are in the same instance (game) they also share all the network host IDs and connection IDs, which results in this behaviour.

If only I could do `new NetworkTransport()`.